# Javawith selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
[TestNGContentHandler] [WARN] It is strongly recommended to add "<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >" at the top of your file, otherwise TestNG may fail or not work as expected.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:\Users\mvars\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:158)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
    at Base.Base.invokeBrowser(Base.java:38)
    at TestSuites.TestCases.invokeBrowser(TestCases.java:20)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:529)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:497)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest invokeBrowser
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.matches(String)" because the return value of "java.util.Properties.getProperty(String)" is null
    at Base.Base.invokeBrowser(Base.java:44)
    at TestSuites.TestCases.invokeBrowser(TestCases.java:20)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:529)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:497)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest closeBrowser
SKIPPED: hotels
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.matches(String)" because the return value of "java.util.Properties.getProperty(String)" is null
    at Base.Base.invokeBrowser(Base.java:44)
    at TestSuites.TestCases.invokeBrowser(TestCases.java:20)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:529)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:497)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

## ===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1

## ===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us what you are asking. The code that is generating the stack trace would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is indicating that there is a problem with the `chromedriver` file that is being used in the Selenium code. The first error message "`java.io.FileNotFoundException`" says that the file cannot be found and the error message "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" is indicating that the file path is incorrect. The second error message "`NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.matches(String)" because the return value of "`java.util.Properties.getProperty(String)" is null`" is indicating that a value from the properties file is null. To fix the issue, you should check the` chromedriver` file path to make sure it is correct and also check the properties file to make sure the value is not null.